I over salted my prime rib! Now what?
In my attempt to cook my first prime rib ever, I researched and researched. I somehow got it into my mind that I needed to Pat Kosher salt all over my boneless roast 24 hours in advance. I panicked when I had forgotten what I thought was the salt step and the roast (6.6lbs) only had around 6hrs of this “salt brine” time.
Well needless to say, after coming to room temp, seating at 450 for 20min and then cooking at 275 for 20min x lbs… I rounded up to 7 lbs. So the roast seared for 20 and the cooked for an additional 2hrs…
I was left with an over-salted mess. It was a disaster! No one wanted seconds and could barely eat their initial serving.
Did I go wrong at salting for 6 hrs?
I think I obviously used too much salt. Can the meat be used for something like soups now? I hate to toss it out. But it’s way tooooooo salty to eat now.

I don't follow what you've done.  Can you clarify?  You patted kosher salt on a 6.6 lb rib roast.  How much salt?  Did it sit this way for 24 hours?  How does the 6 hrs factor in?  Did you add salt in addition to the salt you rubbed on...how much?  (Cooking time is irrelevant in terms of solving the saltiness.)

What I find interesting here is that the name of "kosher salt" comes from it being used to cover meat in a process designed to remove blood and then the salt is washed off (hopefully together with the blood). This is normally done by kosher butcher shops but in ye olden times people would do this themselves with the raw meat before cooking it. But the result is that kosher meat tends to already have more than enough residual salt - so if I found a recipe calling for adding salt to beef I would skip that step. Obviously with non-kosher meat some added salt could be good for flavor.

You have multiple questions in there, but the two main ones:
The time that it was salted probably isn't the issue.  The amount of salt is more likely the issue.  In general, you want about 1% salt by weight (some people say 1.5%, but you can always add more later).  So if you have a 6.6lb roast, that's 3kg, so 30grams of salt. Kosher salt tends to pack differently by brand, so you'll want to look up the density for your brand.
As for uses, just use it as an ingredient in other dishes.  If it's incredibly salty, you might be able to use it like you would salt pork or country ham, so soup as you mentioned (but avoid using salty pre-made broth/stock), but if it's only slightly over salted, you can use it in many ways and just omit the salt:

Fajitas: slice, add lime juice, cook on high heat with onions and bell peppers
Burritos: either cut it into strips or small chunks, mix with rice, vegetables and salsa.  (can also use this mix for stuffed bell peppers)
Beef Stroganoff: sliced beef, onions, mushrooms, sour cream, maybe some herbs, served over egg noodles
Salad: make a green salad, add slices of beef.

If it's crazy salty, you might also want to look up recipes that use corned beef.

if the saltiness level is similar to ham , you might be able to use recipes that would call for that.  Also consider sandwiches, casseroles, cottage pie, etc

Always, always taste the food you are cooking. Caught early enough, you might have been able to marinade the boneless prime ribs in a bottle of strong red wine for an hour and the salt would have seeped into the wine
Now the prime rib is cooked you could reheat it in a dutch oven, chuck in half a bottle of red,  tip in chopped celery, onion, carrots, and later add potatoes–obviously do not season. Potatoes should absorb some of the salt. Taste the stew, still salty? Remove meat and vegetables, reduce the wine to half, add butter, and dissolve a tablespoon of flour. Still salty? So, I would add unsalted tinned tomatoes, sweeten with sugar, and add it all to the stew.

It's difficult to taste a roast as you're seasoning.  I also don't recommend sampling chicken before you've actually cooked it.

@Joe  You can taste the browned side and also the sauce in the roasting pan. You can also touch and taste the seasoning on your finger. Just a dab, it will be such a small amount you'll be safe but if you are concerned you can always spit it out. If the meat is really salty that's your cue something has gone wrong. :)

To some extent, you can "reverse brine" food: soaking food in initially-saltless-water will result in the water becoming more salty and the food becoming less salty. The two main problems are first, this of course means that you're soaking the food in water, so depending on the food you may just be getting mush, and second, it's not just salt that's going to be leached out; any other seasoning will also be pulled out.
The other main thing to do with any food with too much salt (or is too spicy, etc.) is to dilute it. The drawback with that of course is that if you lightly dilute it, then you just have more overly salty (or overly spicy, or whatever you had too much of) stuff, and if you heavily dilute it, then you have a whole lot of food to find something to do with. Whether this is a viable solution (no pun intended) depends on how salty the meat is, and how salty you like your food. If you like soup with high salt content, or chili, or burritos, etc., you could try putting the meat in that. Jerky also might be an option.
You might want to start small, however. As I said before, diluting food can just mean you have more bad tasting stuff. If you start with 1 kg of meat that's ten times too salty and mix it with 2 kg of beans to make chili, well now you have 3 kg of chili that's three times too salty. So make a small batch to check whether it's reducing it to a good salt level before throwing good food after bad. Also beware of the sunk cost fallacy; you may be tempted to dilute it until it's "good enough" and then proceed to eat food that's still too salty, but is edible, just to avoid "wasting it". If you're eating it only to not "waste" it, it's probably not worth it.

your water comment is true about it leaching out other flavors... but that's why you make soup, not just throw out the water.  At a minimum use the water to make rice unless it's unbearably salty (and even then you can use it mixed with water)
